# I want to know why the line 36 causes the assertion failure

Tags: c

According to the error message, the line "strStripped[k] = RemSpecial[i];" causes the debug assertion failed.
Expression: c>=-1 && c <= 255

I don't know what is going on.

I have tried to figure it out by myself. But, I am just a beginner. It is beyond me.

Thank you for your comments in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char OnlyAlphabet(char RemSpecial[]);

int main()
{
char str[50];

printf("Insert the sentence to check the Palindrome: ");
scanf_s("$s", str);

printf("%s\n", OnlyAlphabet(str));

return 0;

}

char OnlyAlphabet(char RemSpecial[])
{
char strStripped[50];
int i;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;
for (i = 0; i < strlen(RemSpecial); i++)
{
    if (isalnum(RemSpecial[i]))
    {
        ***strStripped[k] = RemSpecial[i];***
        k++;
    }
}

strStripped[k] = '\0';

return strStripped;
}
```

Comment: `scanf_s("$s", str);` typo? Try with `"%s"` instead of `"$s"`

Comment: Basic debug: print the variables do they contain what you expect? Surely that is the first thing to do before even posting here?

Comment: How long is **the input**?

Comment: Replace `scanf_s("$s", str);` with `scanf_s("%49s", str);`

Answer (score 0):

Their are a couple problems with your code:

- This line:

  ```
  scanf_s("$s", str);
  ```

  Needs to be instead:

  ```
  scanf_s("%49s", str);
  ```

  `scanf()` needs `%` part of the format specifier,  not `$`. It's good to use `%49s` instead of simply `%s`, which protects `str` from buffer overflow. I also suggest using `scanf()` instead, as its easier to use.
- Your function `char OnlyAlphabet(char RemSpecial[])` only returns `char`. You want it to be `char *`, which  will return a pointer to the modified string `strStripped`.

  However, this means that you cannot allocate this array on the stack like:

  ```
  char strStripped[50];
  ```

  because it will be unwound when the function returns, therefore unsafe to call this function. It will only return the address of a local variable allocated on the stack, which will go out of the picture when the function returns.

  You need to instead allocate a pointer on the heap, so you can share `strStripped` across your program. You can do this will [`malloc`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm).

  > `malloc()` allocates requested memory on the heap, and returns a `void*` pointer to it.

  With respect to your program, this can be achieved like this:

  ```
  char *strStripped = malloc(strlen(RemSpecial)+1);
  ```

  Which allocates block of memory, enough to fit `RemSpecial` and the null-byte character `\0`.

  **Note:** `malloc()` can return `NULL`, which needs to be checked before proceeding. You also need to [`free`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm) this memory at the end of the program, in a safe manner.
- You also don't need `strlen()` as the guard for looping over strings. You can simply loop until the `\0` character is found.

  Your guard can be this instead:

  ```
  RemSpecial[i] != '\0'
  ```

### Your program be modified to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define STRSIZE 50

char *OnlyAlphabet(char RemSpecial[]);

int main(void) {
    char str[STRSIZE];
    char *result;

    printf("Insert the sentence to check the Palindrome: ");
    scanf("%49s", str);

    result = OnlyAlphabet(str);

    printf("%s\n", result);

    free(result);
    result = NULL;

    return 0;
}

char *OnlyAlphabet(char RemSpecial[]) {
    char *strStripped;
    int i, k = 0;

    strStripped = malloc(strlen(RemSpecial)+1);
    if (strStripped == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot allocate string\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; RemSpecial[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (isalnum(RemSpecial[i])) {
            strStripped[k] = RemSpecial[i];
            k++;
        }
    }

    strStripped[k] = '\0';

    return strStripped;
}
```